# Html integration for user end only for moodle

Tags: moodle

How can I integrate my customized theme to only the user end and not to the admin end for moodle. The admin end should remain the same,but when user logins the theme should change.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could work around it

Set the user end theme as the default.

Then go to /admin/settings.php?section=themesettings and ensure the option for allowuserthemes is ticked.

Or add the following line to the config.php file 


    $CFG->allowuserthemes = true;

Then update the admin user themes to the standard

    UPDATE mdl_user SET theme = 'standard';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a separate 'Admin' area in Moodle - it is all the same, with the 'admin' functions being displayed as part of the block.

It is possible to allow users to configure Moodle so that users see a different theme when they log in, or a per-course or per-category theme ( http://docs.moodle.org/en/Theme_settings ).

Be aware, user themes allow users to choose their own theme to display, without changing core Moodle code, you cannot (as far as I know) specify a theme for users and prevent them from changing it.